# Prevent duplicate record entry in text file Java

Tags: java

I have an assignment to write a GUI and have the information written to a text file then when the evaluate button is pressed it will read in the data from the text file sum the required fields and if the total is equal to or greater than 8000 write those records to a new file that it creates. I have everything working pretty well but have hit a wall when it comes to preventing duplicate entries. I would like the program to not allow duplicate entries. I can see that there are duplicates but I can't seem to get the printwriter to not fire. I've tried a boolean for if duplicate records exist but it just blocks the conditional part from writing even to an empty file. Your help is appreciated.

```
    package reprecord;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;





    public class DataEntry extends JFrame
    {
       private JTextField repIDField;
       private JTextField repFirstField;
   private JTextField repLastField;
   private JTextField suppliesField;
   private JTextField booksField;
   private JTextField paperField;
   private JRadioButton northRadioButton;
   private JRadioButton southRadioButton;
   private JRadioButton eastRadioButton;
   private JRadioButton westRadioButton;
   private ButtonGroup districtGroup;
   private JRadioButton phoneRadioButton;
   private JRadioButton emailRadioButton;
   private JRadioButton visitRadioButton;
   private ButtonGroup contactGroup;
   private JButton enterButton;
   private JButton resetButton;
   private JButton evaluateButton;
   private JButton exitButton;
   private JLabel labelRepID; 
   private JLabel labelRepFirst; 
   private JLabel labelRepLast; 
   private JLabel labelSupplies; 
   private JLabel labelBooks; 
   private JLabel labelPaper;
   private JLabel labelDistrict;
   private JLabel labelContact;
   private JPanel p1;
   private JPanel p2;
   private JPanel p3;
   private JPanel p4;
   private JPanel p5;
   private JPanel p6;
   private JPanel p7;
   private JPanel p8;
   private JPanel p9;
   private JPanel p10;
   private JPanel p11;
   private JTextArea eval;
   private JFrame evalFrame;
   private JTextArea star;
   private JFrame starFrame;
   String repID = "";
   String repFirst = "";
   String repLast = "";
   String supplies = "";
   String books = "";
   String paper = "";
   String radioText = "";
   String radioText1 = "";
   private int r1;
   private String r2;
   private String r3;
   private double r4;
   private double r5;
   private double r6;
   private String r7;
   private String r8;
   private int id;
   private int id1;
   String repData;
   String repData1;
   String initData;
   String starData;
   String starData1;
   int J;


public DataEntry()
   {
      super( "Account Representative" );
      setSize(525, 500);
      setVisible(true);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setResizable(false);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      Container c = new Container();
      add(c);
      c.setLayout(new BoxLayout(c, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

      // create and add jpanels for components
      p1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
      c.add(p1);
      p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
      c.add(p2);
      p3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
      c.add(p3);
      p4 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
      c.add(p4);
      p5 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
      c.add(p5);
      p6 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
      c.add(p6);
      p7 = new JPanel();
      c.add(p7);
      p8 = new JPanel();
      c.add(p8);
      p9 = new JPanel();
      c.add(p9);
      p10 = new JPanel();
      c.add(p10);
      p11 = new JPanel();
      c.add(p11);

             evalFrame = new JFrame("Sales Rep Data");
             eval = new JTextArea();
             evalFrame.setVisible(false);
             evalFrame.setSize(575, 300);
             evalFrame.setLocation(1250, 240);
             evalFrame.add(eval);
             eval.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
             eval.setEditable(false);

             File f = new File("salesrep.txt");
             if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) 
             {
             try
                 { // start of try eval
                     FileInputStream fs1 = new FileInputStream("salesrep.txt");
                     DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(fs1);
                     BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));


                 //Read File Line By Line
                 while ((initData = br1.readLine()) != null)   
                         {
                               eval.append(initData + "\r\n");               
                         }//compare while end          

                         in1.close();
                         br1.close();
                 } // end of try eval
             catch (Exception e)
                 {
                    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                 }
             }

             starFrame = new JFrame("Star Sales Rep Data");
             star = new JTextArea();
             starFrame.setVisible(false);
             starFrame.setSize(575, 300);
             starFrame.setLocation(1250, 560);
             starFrame.add(star);
             star.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
             star.setEditable(false);


// create text fields
      labelRepID = new JLabel("Representative ID");
      repIDField = new JTextField( 15 );
      p1.add( labelRepID );
      p1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));
      p1.add( repIDField );
      repIDField.requestFocusInWindow(); 
      p1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100,0)));
      p1.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      p1.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
      p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 0, 0, 0));


      labelRepFirst = new JLabel("Representative First Name");
      repFirstField = new JTextField( 15 );
      p2.add( labelRepFirst );
      p2.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));
      p2.add( repFirstField ); 
      p2.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100,0)));
      p2.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      p2.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

      labelRepLast = new JLabel("Representative Last Name");
      repLastField = new JTextField( 15 );
      p3.add( labelRepLast );
      p3.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));
      p3.add( repLastField );
      p3.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100,0)));
      p3.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      p3.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

      labelSupplies = new JLabel("Supplies Total Sales");
      suppliesField = new JTextField( 15 );
      p4.add( labelSupplies );
      p4.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));
      p4.add( suppliesField );
      p4.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100,0)));
      p4.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      p4.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

      labelBooks = new JLabel("Books Total Sales");
      booksField = new JTextField( 15 ); 
      p5.add( labelBooks );
      p5.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));
      p5.add( booksField );
      p5.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100,0)));
      p5.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      p5.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

      labelPaper = new JLabel("Paper Total Sales");
      paperField = new JTextField( 15 );
      p6.add( labelPaper );
      p6.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));
      p6.add( paperField );
      p6.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100,0)));
      p6.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      p6.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

// register event for textfields
TextFieldHandler handler = new TextFieldHandler();
      repIDField.addActionListener( handler );
      repFirstField.addActionListener( handler );
      repLastField.addActionListener( handler );
      suppliesField.addActionListener( handler );
      booksField.addActionListener( handler );
      paperField.addActionListener( handler );


// create radio buttons
      northRadioButton = new JRadioButton( "North", false );
      southRadioButton = new JRadioButton( "South", false );
      eastRadioButton = new JRadioButton( "East", false );
      westRadioButton = new JRadioButton( "West", false );
      p8.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( null, "Sales District"));
      p8.add( northRadioButton ); 
      p8.add( southRadioButton ); 
      p8.add( eastRadioButton );
      p8.add( westRadioButton );
      p8.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      p8.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

      districtGroup = new ButtonGroup(); 
      districtGroup.add( northRadioButton ); 
      districtGroup.add( southRadioButton ); 
      districtGroup.add( eastRadioButton ); 
      districtGroup.add( westRadioButton ); 

      phoneRadioButton = new JRadioButton( "Phone", false );
      emailRadioButton = new JRadioButton( "Email", false );
      visitRadioButton = new JRadioButton( "Visit", false );
      p9.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 0, 0, 0));
      p10.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( null, "Preferred Contact Method"));
      p10.add( phoneRadioButton ); 
      p10.add( emailRadioButton ); 
      p10.add( visitRadioButton );
      p10.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      p10.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

      contactGroup = new ButtonGroup(); 
      contactGroup.add( phoneRadioButton ); 
      contactGroup.add( emailRadioButton ); 
      contactGroup.add( visitRadioButton ); 

// register events for RadioButtons
RadioButtonHandler handler1 = new RadioButtonHandler();
      northRadioButton.addItemListener( handler1 );
      southRadioButton.addItemListener( handler1 );
      eastRadioButton.addItemListener( handler1 );
      westRadioButton.addItemListener( handler1 );
      phoneRadioButton.addItemListener( handler1 );
      emailRadioButton.addItemListener( handler1 );
      visitRadioButton.addItemListener( handler1 );

// create buttons
      enterButton = new JButton( "   Enter  " ); 
      resetButton = new JButton( "   Reset  " );
      evaluateButton = new JButton( "Evaluate");
      exitButton = new JButton ("   Exit   ");
      p11.add( enterButton );
      p11.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,0)));
      p11.add( resetButton );
      p11.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,0)));
      p11.add( evaluateButton );
      p11.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,0)));
      p11.add(exitButton);
      p11.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      p11.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
      p11.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 0, 5, 0));

// register events for buttons
ButtonHandler handler2 = new ButtonHandler();
      enterButton.addActionListener( handler2 );
      resetButton.addActionListener( handler2 );
      evaluateButton.addActionListener( handler2 );
      exitButton.addActionListener( handler2);
}


private class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener 
   {
      // process textfield events
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
      {

          // user pressed Enter in JTextField repIDField
         if ( event.getSource() == repIDField )
            repID = event.getActionCommand();
            getFocusOwner().transferFocus();

         // user pressed Enter in JTextField repFirstField
         if ( event.getSource() == repFirstField )
            repFirst = event.getActionCommand();
            getFocusOwner().transferFocus();

         // user pressed Enter in JTextField repLastField
         if ( event.getSource() == repLastField )
            repLast = event.getActionCommand();
            getFocusOwner().transferFocus();

         // user pressed Enter in JTextField suppliesField
         if ( event.getSource() == suppliesField )
            supplies = event.getActionCommand();
            getFocusOwner().transferFocus();

         // user pressed Enter in JTextField booksField
         if ( event.getSource() == booksField )
            books = event.getActionCommand();
            getFocusOwner().transferFocus();

         // user pressed Enter in JTextField paperField
         if ( event.getSource() == paperField )
            paper = event.getActionCommand();
            getFocusOwner().transferFocus();
      }

   }


private class RadioButtonHandler implements ItemListener 
   {
      public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent e  )
      {

         if (northRadioButton.isSelected())
         {
             radioText = northRadioButton.getText();
         }

         if (southRadioButton.isSelected())
         {
             radioText = southRadioButton.getText();
         }

         if (eastRadioButton.isSelected())
         {
             radioText = eastRadioButton.getText();
         }

         if (westRadioButton.isSelected())
         {
             radioText = westRadioButton.getText();
         }

         if (phoneRadioButton.isSelected())
         {
             radioText1 = phoneRadioButton.getText();
         }

         if (emailRadioButton.isSelected())
         {
             radioText1 = emailRadioButton.getText();
         }

         if (visitRadioButton.isSelected())
         {
             radioText1 = visitRadioButton.getText();
         }

      }
   }


private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener 
   {
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
      {         
         if (event.getSource() == enterButton)         
         {             
             r1 = Integer.parseInt(repID);
             r2 = repFirst.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + repFirst.substring(1);
             r3 = repLast.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + repLast.substring(1);
             r4 = Double.parseDouble(supplies);
             r5 = Double.parseDouble(books);
             r6 = Double.parseDouble(paper);
             r7 = radioText.toUpperCase();
             r8 = radioText1;        
             repIDField.setText("");
             repID = "";
             repFirstField.setText("");
             repFirst = "";
             repLastField.setText("");
             repLast = "";
             suppliesField.setText("");
             supplies = "";
             booksField.setText("");
             books = "";
             paperField.setText("");
             paper = "";
             contactGroup.clearSelection();
             districtGroup.clearSelection();

             try
             {
                 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("salesrep.txt", true);
                 PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
                 pw.printf("%d %s %s %s $%.2f %s $%.2f %s $%.2f %s %s\r\n",
                 r1, r2, r3, "SUPPLIES", r4, "BOOKS", r5, "PAPER", r6, r7, r8);
                 repData1 = String.format("%d %s %s %s $%.2f %s $%.2f %s $%.2f %s %s\r\n",
                 r1, r2, r3, "SUPPLIES", r4, "BOOKS", r5, "PAPER", r6, r7, r8);
                 eval.append(repData1);
                 evalFrame.setVisible(true);
                 pw.close();
             }
             catch(IOException e)
             {
                 System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
             }
             repIDField.requestFocusInWindow(); 
         }

         if (event.getSource() == resetButton)
         {
             repIDField.setText("");
             repID = "";
             repFirstField.setText("");
             repFirst = "";
             repLastField.setText("");
             repLast = "";
             suppliesField.setText("");
             supplies = "";
             booksField.setText("");
             books = "";
             paperField.setText("");
             paper = "";
             contactGroup.clearSelection();
             districtGroup.clearSelection();
             repIDField.requestFocusInWindow(); 
         }


         if (event.getSource() == evaluateButton)
         {    


             try
             {
                  FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("salesrep.txt");
                  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fs);
                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

             //Read File Line By Line and split at spaces
             while ((repData = br.readLine()) != null)   
             {
                  String[] rd = repData.split(" ");
                  id = Integer.parseInt(rd[0]);
                  String first = rd[1].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + rd[1].substring(1);
                  String last = rd[2].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + rd[2].substring(1);
                  String sup = rd[4];
                  sup = sup.substring(1);
                  double sup1 = Double.parseDouble(sup);
                  String bks = rd[6];
                  bks = bks.substring(1);
                  double bks1 = Double.parseDouble(bks);
                  String pap = rd[8];
                  pap = pap.substring(1);
                  double pap1 = Double.parseDouble(pap);
                  String dis = rd[9].toUpperCase();
                  String con = rd[10];


             File f = new File("stars.txt");
             if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) 
             {      
             try
             {
                  FileInputStream fs1 = new FileInputStream("stars.txt");
                  DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(fs1);
                  BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));

             while ((starData = br1.readLine()) != null)   
             {
                  String[] rd1 = starData.split(" ");
                  id1 = Integer.parseInt(rd1[0]);
                  if(id == id1)
                  {
                       System.out.printf("\n%s %d %s", "Duplicate Record Item " , id, "\n");
                       int i = id;
                       i++;
                       System.out.print(i);
                  }
             }

             }
            catch (Exception e)
                     {
                        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                     }
             }

                  double total = (sup1 + bks1 + pap1);

                if(total >= 8000) 
                {
                    try
                         {                                                    
                         FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter("stars.txt", true);           
                         PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(fw1);
                         pw1.printf("%d %s %s %s $%.2f %s $%.2f %s $%.2f %s %s\r\n",
                         id, first, last, "SUPPLIES", sup1, "BOOKS", bks1, "PAPER", pap1, dis, con);
                         starData1 = String.format("%d %s %s %s $%.2f %s $%.2f %s $%.2f %s %s\r\n",
                         id, first, last, "SUPPLIES", sup1, "BOOKS", bks1, "PAPER", pap1, dis, con);
                         star.append(starData1);
                         pw1.close();


                         }
                    catch(IOException e)
                         {
                            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                         } 
                }
                        evalFrame.setVisible(true); 
                        starFrame.setVisible(true);

                }  
                         in.close();
                         br.close();
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
             }       

         } // end evaluate button


         if (event.getSource() == exitButton)
         {
             System.exit(0);
         }
      }// end of actionperformed
    }// end of buttonhandler 




}// end of DataEntry class
```

Comment: Could it be possible to narrow down your code example to be more concise?

Comment: My text editor says it is 500+ lines of code.

Comment: Hint: If you need to annotate the end brackets of your code blocks then you have a spagetti code problem.

Comment: just as a tip, when declaring variables that have not been initialized, you can do to save space and make it neater: `String repData, repData1, initData, starData, starData1;`